# Why multiple screenshots caused the system to crash on android?

Tags: android

I need to keep getting screenshots for a long time. But it makes the system crash.
This is my `MainActivity`

About 220 times, the system will crash.

I guess it may be caused by a memory leak, but I can't find it.

phone: oneplus 7 pro

OS: Oxygen OS (Android 9)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1050;
    private String TAG = "Service";
    private MainApplication mainApplication;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mainApplication = (MainApplication) getApplication();

        if (MainApplication.sceenWidth == 0 || MainApplication.sceenHeight == 0) {
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(dm);
            MainApplication.sceenHeight = Math.min(dm.heightPixels, dm.widthPixels);
            MainApplication.sceenWidth = Math.max(dm.heightPixels, dm.widthPixels);
            MainApplication.dpi = dm.densityDpi;
        }

//        mainApplication.init(this);

        ScreenCaptureUtilByMediaPro.mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        // init
        startActivityForResult(ScreenCaptureUtilByMediaPro.mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);


    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (RESULT_OK == resultCode && REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
            ScreenCaptureUtilByMediaPro.data = data;
            ScreenCaptureUtilByMediaPro.resultCode = resultCode;
            ScreenCaptureUtilByMediaPro.init();

        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            Bitmap screenCap = ScreenCaptureUtilByMediaPro.getScreenCap();
            System.out.println(screenCap);
            System.out.println(i);
            i++;
            sleep(2000);
        }
        }
    }


}
```

And other class:

```
public class ScreenCaptureUtilByMediaPro {
    public static MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;
    public static Intent data;
    public static int resultCode;
    private static MediaProjection sMediaProjection;
    private static ImageReader mImageReader;
    private static VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;

    private static Bitmap bitmapCache;

    public static void init() {
        sMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        //start capture reader
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(MainApplication.sceenWidth, MainApplication.sceenHeight,
                PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
        mVirtualDisplay = sMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(
                "ScreenShot",
                MainApplication.sceenWidth,
                MainApplication.sceenHeight,
                MainApplication.dpi,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC,
                mImageReader.getSurface(),
                null,
                null);
    }


    /**
     * 
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Deprecated
    public static Bitmap getScreenCap() {

        Bitmap bitmap;
        android.media.Image image;
        do {
            image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage();
            if (image == null && bitmapCache != null) {
                return bitmapCache;
            }
        } while (image == null);
        bitmap = covetBitmap(image);
        if (bitmapCache != null) {
            bitmapCache.recycle();
            bitmapCache = null;
        }
        bitmapCache = bitmap;
        return bitmap;
    }


    public static Bitmap covetBitmap(android.media.Image image) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        final android.media.Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
        final ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
        int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
        int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
        int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width + rowPadding / pixelStride, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height);
        image.close();
        return bitmap;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please show your **logcat** with the error.

Comment: @JonGoodwin  No any errors!

Comment: Your headline to the question is **"Why multiple screenshots caused the system to crash on android?"** You also say *"About 220 times, the system will crash."** And you get **NO** errors ? You need to debug it then, or use a memory leak tool.

Comment: Try [leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)